# Rails 3 CSRF_meta_tag not functioning

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-3-upgrade

I am in the process of upgrading my app from Rails 2.3 to Rails 3. I read that I need to insert

> <%= csrf_meta_tag %>

in my layouts, which I did. Unfortunately, when I used ajax requests, I kept being logged out. After a little research, I found an older way was to add

```
$j(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
  var token =$j("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", token);  
});
```

in my application.js file. It now works properly (It seems I actually don't need the csrf_meta_tag).

Is it normal I had to add these 4 lines of code in my application.js instead of just the csrf_meta_tag, or am I just missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, you do need csrf_meta_tag. If you don't use it in your layout the **csrf-token** meta will not be generated then your application.js fix stops working.

The `jquery-ujs` gem (jquery-rails) should take care of this for you. It's possible the version you use have some bug. (I do remember there's a related bug in 3.0.x, but couldn't recall the exact issue). Try updating jquery-ujs and re-generate jquery (`rails generate jquery:install`), remove rails.js to see if the issue be fixed.

Bonus note: as of rails 3.1, csrf_meta_tag has been renamed to csrf_meta_tags, but the former one could still be used.

Please see [jquery-ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) on github.

Comment: sorry, I'm a little confused: I can't find any jquery-ujs gem (added it to my Gemfile and can't locate it, running rails generate query:install says it can't find the generator query:install). Does it come with rails? And what's Jquery-urj?

Comment: my bad. It's called jquery-ujs but the gem name is jquery-rails. see https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs. Please follow its readme. jquery-urj is a typo I'm going to update the answer.

Comment: Another typo is that the generate command is really "rails generate jquery:install"

Comment: Well, tried to edit the jquery:install but it was rejected, hope people pay attention to the comments before copy-pasting then.